# Creating a PHP installation script

Tags: php

Let's say I have created a PHP script and I want every time someone opens it in localhost/his web server to get redirected to the installation directory

Do I have to modify .htaccess and add **DirectoryIndex Install.php** or there is another way?

Thanks in advance :)

P.S: I have already created the installation script.

Comment: you can ask these kind of question on http://www.reddit.com/r/webdev/ .in here people just help with your codes. you need to make something.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Comment: What purpose does the installation script serve? If it's installing DB tables, you should check the existence of those, and then handle installation. Remember, that an installation could have been aborted or corrupted.

Answer (score 1):

You can check installer with adding below codes your script index file header:

With File Existence:

```
//if the install file doesn't exist, the script hasn't been installed.
if(file_exists(dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']).'/install.php'))
{
    $folder = dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
    $path   = rtrim($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$folder, '/\\').'/';  
    header('Location: http://'.$path.'install.php');
    die;
}
```

With DB Existence:

```
//if the install file doesn't exist, the script hasn't been installed.
if(mysql_select_db('db_name'))
{
    $folder = dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
    $path   = rtrim($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$folder, '/\\').'/';  
    header('Location: http://'.$path.'install.php');
    die;
}
```

Comment: This considers that the user removes the install.php after the "install" not always the correct method for example if updates are ran through the install script itself.

Comment: Installation is completed or not, how do you think to check installation? you can change install.php with db existence or anything.

Comment: Agreed, just to give it a fuller answer, i would suggest adding the DB check to your answer!

Comment: I updated code with db existence.. I hope, it provides your issue.

Comment: Please don't recommend `mysql_*`. There are enough outdated recommendations to this deprecated function set already...

Comment: @BenM You right! So what can be used instead of mysql_*?

Answer (score 0):

I always have multiple values inserted to the database to indicate installation status. If those values are missing, it indicates no installation performed or installation needs to be run to repair a broken install.

The same system in my scripts is used to trigger updating. So think ahead on that part. Do you want users to be shown a update information and button to initial any update?

I treat installation as a state not just action i.e. I make my applications constantly check installation state and I do so when the user is not performing actions in order to avoid too much processing. If something is found to be wrong with the installation, my applications force the user to view Install/Update screen where information will be displayed regarding the possible fault.

No forwarding is done. Instead very early in my script I have an if argument that checks a variable which indicates overall installation state. So if $installstate = true then load the application as normal, if $installstate = false then there is a problem so load the Install/Update screen.

A range of others values are used to create an intelligent installation/update process. Maybe a bit more than you want to create but no installation system is fool proof without diagnostics. Considering if there is a fault during an initial install, user tampers with the install or a hacker. So the diagnostic system ties in with the install and rather than doing a forward to a file I hope is still there. I simply call some functions.